# ¿como hacer para que cuando presiono un boton en tkinter, no se bloquee el otro boton?

Tags: tkinter

Tengo 4 botones en una aplicación *tkinter* que al presionarlos llama a una función, pero cuando quiero presionar otro botón, no me permite hacerlo hasta que se termine de ejecutar. Yo quisiera ir presionando varios botones y que se ejecuten las funciones de cada botón.
¿Cómo puedo hacer eso?. Gracias!

**código**

```
import tkinter as tk
from test import (func_reporte_1, func_reporte_2)
from test2 import (func_reporte_3, func_reporte_4)

class Aplicacion:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ventana1 = tk.Tk()
        self.ventana1.title("Tablero Reporte por empresa")
        self.ventana1.geometry('300x300')
        self.ventana1.config(bg = '#eceff1')
        self.ventana1.resizable(width=False, height=False)

        self.boton1 = tk.Button(self.ventana1, text="Boton1", command=self.reporte1)
        self.boton1.config(bg = '#0097a7', fg = 'white', bd = 0, font = ('Modern',  12),
                           width = 12, height = 2, padx = 2, pady = 2, relief='flat',  highlightbackground = '#0097a7')                  
        self.boton1.place(x = 18, y = 36)

        self.boton2 = tk.Button(self.ventana1, text="Boton2", command=self.reporte2)
        self.boton2.config(bg = '#0097a7', fg = 'white', bd = 0, font = ('Modern',  12),
                           width = 12, height = 2, padx = 2, pady = 2, relief='flat', highlightbackground = '#0097a7')
        self.boton2.place(x = 150, y = 36)

        self.boton3 = tk.Button(self.ventana1, text="Boton3", command=self.reporte3)
        self.boton3.config(bg = '#0097a7', fg = 'white', bd = 0, font = ('Modern',  12),
                           width = 12, height = 2, padx = 2, pady = 2, relief='flat', highlightbackground = '#0097a7')
        self.boton3.place(x = 18, y = 80)

        self.boton4 = tk.Button(self.ventana1, text="Boton4", command=self.reporte4)
        self.boton4.config(bg = '#0097a7', fg = 'white', bd = 0, font = ('Modern',  12), 
                           width = 12, height = 2, padx = 2, pady = 2, relief='flat', highlightbackground = '#0097a7')
        self.boton4.place(x = 150, y = 80)

    self.ventana1.mainloop()
```

**Llamo a las funciones**

```
def reporte1(self):
    func_reporte_1()

def reporte2(self):
    func_reporte_2()    

def reporte3(self):
    func_reporte_3()

def reporte4(self):
    func_reporte_4()     


aplicacion1 = Aplicacion()
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema se debe a que cuando el botón llama a una de las funciones, la ventana de Tkinter se "bloquea" hasta que termina de ejecutarse la función.
Esto sucede por que la función NO es asincrónica.
Para que un código se ejecute asincrónicamente, podemos crear una nueva tarea con la clase Thread del modulo [threading](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/#starting-a-thread). El propósito de esta clase llamar a la función pasada por el parametro target en una tarea separada. Por lo tanto, el código no se traba durante la ejecución de dicha función y, debido a esto, tampoco se traba la ventana de Tkinter.

Aquí te dejo un código de ejemplo que llama a funciones cuya ejecución dura aproximadamente 2 segundos.

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import time

def func_reporte_1():
    time.sleep(2)
    print("ejecutada funcion 1")

def func_reporte_2():
    time.sleep(2)
    print("ejecutada funcion 2")

def func_reporte_3():
    time.sleep(2)
    print("ejecutada funcion 3")

def func_reporte_4():
    time.sleep(2)
    print("ejecutada funcion 4")

class Aplicacion:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ventana1 = tk.Tk()
        self.ventana1.title("Tablero Reporte por empresa")
        self.ventana1.geometry('300x300')
        self.ventana1.config(bg = '#eceff1')
        self.ventana1.resizable(width=False, height=False)

        self.boton1 = tk.Button(self.ventana1, text="Boton1", command=self.reporte1)
        self.boton1.config(bg = '#0097a7', fg = 'white', bd = 0, font = ('Modern',  12),
                           width = 12, height = 2, padx = 2, pady = 2, relief='flat',  highlightbackground = '#0097a7')                  
        self.boton1.place(x = 18, y = 36)

        self.boton2 = tk.Button(self.ventana1, text="Boton2", command=self.reporte2)
        self.boton2.config(bg = '#0097a7', fg = 'white', bd = 0, font = ('Modern',  12),
                           width = 12, height = 2, padx = 2, pady = 2, relief='flat', highlightbackground = '#0097a7')
        self.boton2.place(x = 150, y = 36)

        self.boton3 = tk.Button(self.ventana1, text="Boton3", command=self.reporte3)
        self.boton3.config(bg = '#0097a7', fg = 'white', bd = 0, font = ('Modern',  12),
                           width = 12, height = 2, padx = 2, pady = 2, relief='flat', highlightbackground = '#0097a7')
        self.boton3.place(x = 18, y = 80)

        self.boton4 = tk.Button(self.ventana1, text="Boton4", command=self.reporte4)
        self.boton4.config(bg = '#0097a7', fg = 'white', bd = 0, font = ('Modern',  12), 
                           width = 12, height = 2, padx = 2, pady = 2, relief='flat', highlightbackground = '#0097a7')
        self.boton4.place(x = 150, y = 80)

        self.ventana1.mainloop()

    def reporte1(self):
        # Le indicamos a la tarea que función debe ejecutar.
        threading.Thread(target=func_reporte_1).start()

    def reporte2(self):
        threading.Thread(target=func_reporte_2).start()

    def reporte3(self):
        threading.Thread(target=func_reporte_3).start()

    def reporte4(self):
        threading.Thread(target=func_reporte_4).start()   


aplicacion1 = Aplicacion()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación y el ejemplo Dante!!. Lo voy a probar y te cuento.